# Hover DIV then display another div *without re-positioning* it

Tags: html, css

This is what I tried.
CSS:

```
div#Layer3:hover div#Layer3copy
{ 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="Layer3"><img src="images/Layer3.png">
        <div id="Layer3copy"><img src="images/Layer3copy.png"></div>            
    </div>
```

I want this div to be hidden and when hover another div it appear, however, its working OK,

But moved a little bit from it actual place,

is there a solution for it?

Comment: From this peace of code we cannot see the reason of div's moving. I'd suggest you to create [JsFiddle](jsfiddle.net) with fuller html and css of your page.

Comment: Was the div originally inline-block? maybe if it was block element and changing to inline makes the difference of position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, first you need to know display,position and pseudo state properties of CSS
in your snippet #Layer3 is wrapping #Layer3copy so we can invoke it on hover state by using direct child selector i.e

```
#Layer3:hover > #Layer3copy{
   /*Do your things here*/
  }
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ishusupah/eupfr101/

In this example as you wanted i am using #Layer3copy display:none and on hover state i am making it display:block.

you can display and position however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are not hiding/showing any div. What you are actually doing in the code above is when `Layer3 div` is hovered on, you are changing `Layer3copy div` style to be `inline block` - and that's why it is moving. A div is by default a `block` element - which means it is taking up a full width of a row. When you change it to an `inline-block` you are "telling" the div to align next to another element if there is enough width in a row, and not take the full width - that's why the div is moving next to the parent div.

You also need to modify your selectors to achieve your requirement.

To actually achieve what you want (hiding and displaying back the `Layer3copy` without it being moving), use this CSS code:

```
#Layer3 #Layer3copy{
  display: none;
}

#Layer3:hover #Layer3copy{
border: 3px solid red;
display: block;
}
```

The first selector is giving the default definition when `layer3` - the container div is not hovered - in which the child `Layer3copy` div is not displayed (`display:none`).

The second selector is saying when `layer3` is hovered apply styling to `Layer3copy` and turn it to `display:block` - which is the default display for `divs` (they are block elements) - this it is getting displayed and staying it its initial position without "movement".

[Here is a working example with the above code.](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/886/)

I've additionally added a thin red border to the inner div, so you'll see what i mean in a `block` element - which is taking the entire width of a row.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
#Layer3:hover > #Layer3Copy {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
/** Postion of your div **/
}
```

Try to adjust the position until it is placed wherever you want it to be in.
I think you want to be like a tooltip or something